# How to find the Bytecode of Ethereum Smart Contract by just it's address using JSON RPC

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, json-rpc

I am wondering that is there any way to find the byte-code of the Smart Contract which is published on a blockchain just by having only idea about it's contract address using JSON RPC running at 8545 port?

I was thinking to use `eth_getStorageAt` and bruteforce the value of the block. But, it is not working well.

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is [`eth_getCode`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getcode):

> Returns code at a given address.

Example:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getCode","params":["0x0289eC8BDFBF5f6d90102E752e674F18f7a8Ed03", "latest"],"id":1}' http://127.0.0.1:8545

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"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"}
```

Example with Geth:

```
> eth.getCode("0x0289eC8BDFBF5f6d90102E752e674F18f7a8Ed03")
"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"
```

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x0289eC8BDFBF5f6d90102E752e674F18f7a8Ed03#contracts

Comment: Do you need to supply Block-number to it. or web3 will just handle it by itself?

Comment: Hm @alberto, It seems that `latest` will only check whether the contract exist on the latest block, isn't it? If I have a blockchain which is mining block based on transaction which don't contain that contract. Will it still be able to find it using `latest` keyword because I think it wont be included in `latest`.

Comment: `latest` determines the height of the block. If you prefer to use `eth_getCode` with a block number, you need to provide a block number after the contract creation. I can't prove that because my node is not running in `syncmode full`.

Comment: I see, so the JSON RPC will find relevant block by itself and fetch the contract data from the input address right? @alberto

Comment: @Stefan Yes, if you provide a contract address, JSON RPC will find it with the block parameter you provided. You can read about the block parameter here: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#the-default-block-parameter